# Play music in queue through Av player

Tags: iphone

Please suggest me play music in queue.
Actually I have array of songs url from web. I success to play the songs through AV player on clik of songs  cell. I want to play songs automatically one be one like in queue.please help me  how can do this only av player...

Thanks..........

Answer (score 0):

use this AVAudio Player Delegate

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer successfully:(BOOL)flag
```

Study AVAudioPlayer Class Reference - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

You will have so many ways for your task.

Comment: Study the question, it is about avplayer, not avaudioplayer

Comment: @rakeshNS yes..and i gave him a substitute solution.